# Checking Negative Numbers Javascript Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I read around a ton trying to find an answer to what I am looking for. I have found several related posts but none of them answered my question. I am doing some custom work for Netsuite and all is done in javascript. I am still new to coding, by no means am I an advanced coder. So what I am trying to do I thought would be simple. I want to check to see if a number is negative. Most posts say something like this:
    if(x < 0){
    //do something
}
But here is my problem. For example, if I do var x = 2-7; My alert box gives the answer to that as 5. So if I do the simple if check above it will never be true. Am I missing something? The answer should be -5. I would post code but I am simply creating a variable and any math I do that should make the number negative is not working. All numbers are positive. No matter what.

Comment: can you post some of your code? 2-7 IS -5 in JS, so something else might be modifying your value in transit.

Comment: Yes please post a snippet of your SuiteScript code. Especially if you are retrieving your values from NetSuite fields, NetSuite tends to present them to you as Strings; this might be causing some calculation errors. If we can see a bit of the actual SuiteScript code in question, we'll be able to help much better.

Comment: Resolved. I jumped into this code and noticed the person before was doing a math.abs on the number previously. Found it and changed and all is good now.